# Is it 'Were' or 'Was'? (For specific example)

Tags: word-usage, subjunctives

> Born from his canal **was** two ideas.

vs

> Born from his canal **were** two ideas.

I'm using a nonsensical sentence for the sake of an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the sentence is inverted, you still must conjugate the verb to match the subject.  "Two ideas" is the subject, so the verb must reflect the plural.

Write it in a more typical order and it should be clear:

> Two ideas **were** born from his canal.

Other examples

> At the juncture of five states **lives** the genius.
>
> Beneath the harvest moon **dance** the sisters.
>
> Far away beneath the Misty Mountains **lie** the fabled Mines of Moria.

BTW, this inverted sentence structure has a kind of *dramatic*, even *epic* feel to it, as if it is part of a grand story.  It is not something to use casually or lightly, at least until you understand the nuance.